# how insert multiple images name?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

    $summernote = $_POST['summernote'];
    $head =$_POST['head'];
    $txtprice=$_POST['txtprice'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $new_date = date('d-F-Y', strtotime($date));
    $img = addslashes($_POST['img']);
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `news` (`id`,`image`,`heading`,`description`,`date`,`category_id`) VALUES ('','$img','$head','$summernote','$new_date ','$txtprice')");

    $a=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `news_sub`(`id`,`subimage`,`category`) VALUES ('','$img','$txtprice')");

    print "Successfully inserted";`enter code here`
    ?>
```

This is the insert query of form submission .Here i selecting multiple images at a time.At the time of insertion only single images value is inserting.i want to insert all images name into single row in a database.

Comment: YOU NEED TO CHECK `$_FILES` for that

Comment: Post your html code too

Comment: why would you want to `"insert all images name into single row"`? Into which field would the image details be placed? This code is vulnerable to sql injection. There is no javascript in the question.